# Having issues displaying time values on the X-Axis on a MS-Access Modern Chart

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to chart out a trendline on a modern chart in an Access report that contains about 2800 to 5600 rows of data. I have been able to plot said data points successfully however I need the X-Axis of the chart to properly display the current time in this format "hh:nn".

I have so far been unable to achieve this result. I have got this to work using a standard Microsoft chart, but the standard Microsoft chart seems to have a row limit of 3999 rows of data which will not work with my use case.

Picture 1 is of the modern chart I need to list the X-Axis values on and picture 2 is of the legacy chart which seems to have a row limit of 3999 rows of data. For clarity, the current dataset the charts are using consists of 4738 Rows of data.
[image: Picture of the Modern Chart]

[image: Picture of the Legacy Chart]

Below is the query that I am using to display the data on the chart.

```
SELECT [_tempTbl].DateAndTimeVar, [_tempTbl].hrsMinutes,[_tempTbl].PRES, [_tempTbl].TEMP, [_tempTbl].VAC
FROM _tempTbl
ORDER BY [_tempTbl].DateAndTimeVar;
```

Table with sample data.

| DateAndTimeVar | hrsMinutes | PRES | TEMP | VAC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/7/2023 7:09:47 AM | 07:09 | 0 | 91.6069869995117 | 0.185184478759766 |
| 12/7/2023 7:10:07 AM | 07:10 | 0 | 91.6883697509766 | 0.185184478759766 |
| 12/7/2023 7:11:07 AM | 07:11 | 0 | 91.8330459594727 | 0.135272979736328 |
| 12/7/2023 7:12:27 AM | 07:12 | 0 | 92.0048446655273 | 0.218460083007813 |
| 12/7/2023 7:21:37 AM | 07:21 | 1.78747177124023 | 174.650970458984 | 0 |

The DateAndTimeVar is a Datetime2 datatype.
Below are the chart settings for my modern chart.

[image: Chart Settings]

Link to exmaple dataset used in all pictures of graphs provided.
[Dropbox link for example dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/f14j6z1yx3h8hnvbs9ryv/h?rlkey=fyai7uyl5yw5u44stsbtqwav1&dl=0)

Thanks for reading and any help or input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 5600 records is hardly a 'vast' amount of data. What do you mean you want to display "current time" - don't you want to display data from table? Why are hrs/minutes in separate field? The query you show does not filter nor aggregate data - you want to display 5600 data points? Edit question to show a sample of data - as formatted text table, not image or post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis (although I possibly won't be able to open it with Access 2010 because of the Datetime2 datatype and certainly can't test ModernChart).

Comment: Isn't first field in query used as X-axis data? Is posted query used for classic chart?

Comment: Posted Query is used for modern chart's row source. The classic chart also uses the same query. @June7 Thanks for the response. I am adding an example table now. Also, this is using Access 2016 I will update the tags accordingly my apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Could you answer other questions?

Comment: I confirmed the 3999 limit for classic MSGraph in Access. However, not really understanding your issue. The image shows hh:mm on x axis. Although, I don't understand why it's not using DateAndTimeVar field for x axis.

Comment: @June7: all data points are from the same day, so it makes sense to use a time-only column (hrsMinutes). for the x-axis. The problem seems to be that the modern chart doesn't display the x-axis legend.

Comment: @Dadams: I don't have a record source with time values readily available. But a line chart with 7000 dates + values shows the x-axis legend just fine, I can also select which level of legend grouping I want to have. -- Can you add a screenshot of design view, with the chart settings visible?

Comment: Sure thing, I will add that shortly. Would a CSV file with the dataset I'm using also be beneficial? @Andre

Comment: @June7 hrs/minutes are in a separate field due to me trying to find a solution to the problems I was having, And yes I would like to display 5600 data points unaggregated data.

Comment: @Dadams: yes, that would be useful. I'm too lazy to generate my own data... ;-)

Comment: Why are field names in chart settings different from field names shown in query?

Comment: Sorry I have been updating the query and chart since I posted the image of my display setting my apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I couldn't get it to work with a datetime column containing time values.

I changed `hrsMinutes` to Short Text and filled it with:

```
UPDATE _tempTbl SET hrsMinutes = TimeValue([DateAndTimeVar]);
```

Then the chart picks up the x-axis values automatically.

It also works with a query, using `CStr(TimeValue([DateAndTimeVar]))`. It must be a string, not a date/time.

[image: Modern Chart]